# Is it bad practice to call a static method via an object?

Tags: php, oop

I found that calling the static method via object can be very convenient in some use case.

I'm wondering if this is is considered as a bad practice?

or if this feature will be removed in the future version of PHP?

```
class Foo
{
    public static function bar ()
    {
        echo 'hi';
    }
}

class SubFoo extends Foo
{
    public static function bar ()
    {
        echo 'hi subfoo';
    }
}

// The normal way to call a static method.
Foo::bar(); // => "hi"

// Call the static method via instance.
$foo = new Foo;
$foo::bar(); // => "hi"


// Here is the use case I found calling static method via instance is convenient.
function callbar(Foo $foo) 
{
  // The type-hinting `Foo` can be any subclass of `Foo`
  // so I have to figure out the class name of `$foo` by calling `get_class`.
  $className = get_class($foo);
  $className::bar();

  // Instead of the above, I can just do `$foo::bar();`
}

callbar(new SubFoo); // => "hi subfoo"
```

Comment: You could also make your function not static and just call `$foo->bar();` in your `callbar` function as you're type-hinting it with `Foo`.

Comment: @Daan yeah.. you can make all your static methods to instance method, which means we don't need the static method at all. Obviously this is a really bad idea. We use the `static` keyword because we want to let the user know we are calling the method which do not depending on the individual instance object. That's why the static keyword was introduced.

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule, using static methods is bad practice because:

1. In fact, static methods or static variables are global variables
2. static code makes can cause many troubles in testing
3. static code makes high cohesion between parts of code
4. static code makes hidden dependencies between parts of code

But, there are cases when using static code is justified. For example:

1. Methods refer to a class and don't refer to objects
2. Helpers or Util classes which don't have their states